# Antimation to change the color of div border every second with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of a div border, so that the color changes every second to another color.

I don't know how to do this, any help? This is my code.

```css
/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: 3px solid;
  border-left-color: #FF0000;
  border-top-color: #F5FF00;
  border-top-style: double;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  border-bottom-color: #FF0000;
  border-right-style: double;
  border-right-color: #F5FF00;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="topnav" id="drop">
    <li><a class="selected" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="project.html">Project</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="project.html">Algemeen</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test2.html">test2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: You can't do it just with `HTML` and `CSS`. You need to write some `JavaScript` code.

Comment: Everything i could, i don't know where to start

Comment: If anyone has a javascript for me i could use, it would really help

Comment: @Ali he can use `keyframes` in css.

Comment: @Dave by using css animations! yeah that works!

Answer (score 10):

If you know the sequence of the colors or simply you don't care, you can use a CSS rule called [@Keyframes animation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp), it is compatible with most of the modern [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation) and you can do a lot of tricky things like this:

```css
.border-glow {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  animation: 4s infinite glow;
}
@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: purple;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="border-glow">Shiny!</div>
```

[Working jdfiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/bopdh6ta/)

Comment: Thanks, how do i apply this to my border? If i apply it my double border will change

Comment: Can i also give border-right and border-left a different color changer?

Comment: @BernardBierbuik yes of course, you can use something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bopdh6ta/2/

Comment: @BernardBierbuik If you want it with double border just modfy `border: 1px solid blue;` to `border: 5px double blue;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.border-glow {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  animation: 4s infinite glow;
}
@keyframes glow {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: purple;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  0% {
    border-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    border-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="border-glow">Shiny!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  --color-jelles: #dc3376;
}

.border-glow {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0.3rem;
  border-color: var(--color-jelles);
  animation: 7s infinite glow;
}

@keyframes glow {
  25% {
    border-top: 5px solid var(--color-jelles);
    border-right: 5px solid red;
    border-bottom: 5px solid greenyellow;
    border-left: 5px solid orangered;
  }

  50% {
    border-top: 5px solid orangered;
    border-right: 5px solid var(--color-jelles);
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    border-left: 5px solid greenyellow;
  }

  75% {
    border-top: 5px solid greenyellow;
    border-right: 5px solid orangered;
    border-bottom: 5px solid var(--color-jelles);
    border-left: 5px solid red;
  }

  100% {
    border-top: 5px solid red;
    border-right: 5px solid greenyellow;
    border-bottom: 5px solid orangered;
    border-left: 5px solid var(--color-jelles);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="border-glow">WHATEVER!</div>
```

This is what I made and this is my source:

https://codepen.io/Thisisguill/pen/abaXPaQ